# Moderador pode marcar uma pergunta como certa?

Tags: support, accepted-answer

***Português:***

**Todos nós sabemos que muita gente só entra aqui, faz uma pergunta e vaza...**

*E a minha pergunta é:*

> Se eu responder corretamente uma pergunta de uma pessoa e ela ficar
>   AFK e não entrar mais, um moderador pode marcar a minha pergunta como
>   certa?

---

***English:***

**We all know that a lot of people just enter here, make one question and never more appears...**

*And my question is:*

> If I correctly answer a question of someone and this person doesn't enter      more in the site, can a moderator mark my answer as right?

Comment: "um***a*** pergunta"; "[***b***aza](http://priberam.pt/dlpo/bazar)"

Comment: Yes, "Away Keyboard From"

Comment: For language-specific Stack Exchange sites to work, it's important that meta posts written in non-English have an English translation included below --  please update your post to include one.

Comment: Edited.........

Comment: Oh Sorry @Math, it's "Away From Keyboard"

Comment: No problem :)​​

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Não, somente o autor da pergunta (AP) pode marcar uma resposta como certa. É mesmo para isso que serve o visto. Para o AP identificar qual a resposta que ela acha que é a mais correta ou que mais o ajudou.

Para validar as respostas temos os votos que identificam a melhor resposta, na opinião da comunidade.

Recentemente tivemos [essa discussão no SOpt](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4089/marcar-resposta-correta-por-consenso).

Segundo o @Gabe,

> O Stack Overflow nasceu para solucionar um problema bem específico:
>   não era possível encontrar respostas para dúvidas de programação de
>   maneira *rápida* e *confiável*. Não era uma falta completa de lugares
>   onde programadores podiam conversar ou tirar dúvidas, esses locais
>   existiam mas falhavam em um, ou ambos, desses requerimentos.
>
> No caso da *rapidez*, o caso mais óbvio eram os fóruns. Perguntas
>   feitas lá eram debatidas incessantemente - o que não é necessariamente
>   ruim - e qualquer tentativa de resposta era coletivamente construida
>   aos poucos, tendendo a se perder em um mar de conversas transversais
>   ou paralelas. Não era possível saber se o problema tinha sido
>   completamente solucionado, ou onde estava a solução correta.
>
> Quanto à *confiabilidade*, o problema era saber qual das várias
>   respostas oferecidas era a melhor, se ela realmente solucionava o
>   problema. Haviam outros sites de perguntas e respostas (a Microsoft
>   tinha um no MSDN, eu acho) mas os votos funcionavam de maneira
>   diferente, e outros usuários (no caso da MS, seus MVPs) podiam marcar
>   respostas como corretas.
>
> Dar a terceiros o poder de marcar respostas parece fazer sentido,
>   tanto por justiça com quem escreveu uma resposta correta quanto em
>   termos de organização do site. O problema é que isso fere diretamente
>   a *confiabilidade* das respostas. Uma resposta aceita nos Stack
>   Overflows automaticamente inspira confiança, porque necessariamente
>   passou pelo crivo da única pessoa 100% capacitada para avaliá-la. Isso
>   é algo fácil de desmerecer hoje, mas que fez muita diferença 7 anos
>   atrás e também para qualquer usuário que conhece o site hoje.
>
> Não há nenhuma maneira funcional de dar esse poder a terceiros sem
>   automaticamente desvalorizar o significado da resposta aceita, não
>   interessa quantos requerimentos sejam implementados. E o valor tácito
>   das respostas aceitas, a confiança que elas inspiram, é parte muito
>   importante do sucesso dos Stack Overflows.

Comment: Eu já ia debater com você aqui mas eu li a discussão e umas repostas me fizeram mudar de ideia...